# How can I automatically initialize an array of structs to 0

Tags: c, language-lawyer

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883722/c-how-does-nested-braces-for-array-of-struct-initialization-work), but I think subtly different.

I know that when you have an initializer list for a local variable, either an array or a struct, then any element(s) and/or field(s) omitted are automatically initialized to 0. With no initializer list at all, then the local variable contains garbage (unless static).

I know if the left hand side is an array or struct, then the right hand side must be an initializer list (except I guess with string literals for a `char[]`). The very last example here with `s9` confirms that initializing a struct won't work without an initializer list.

`s2` is an example omitting fields. `s3` an example of omitting array elements. `s4` is omitting both.

Now `s5` and `s6` I am confused about. They have an outer initializer list `= {...}` good for the array initialization. But each element of the array is a struct. So how can they be initialized with an `int` value `0`, which is not a `struct S`?

I mean for `s5` and `s6` apparently the compiler *can* convert from `int` to `S` (using the exact language of the error message), but it cannot for `s9`.

It appears like 1 initializer list, at the outermost level, is good enough for the compiler.

```
typedef struct S
{
    int a;
    int b;
} S;

int main(void)
{
    S s1[] = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
    S s2[] = {{0}, {0}};
    S s3[] = {{0, 0}};
    S s4[] = {{0}};
    S s5[] = {0, 0}; /* why is this allowed? */
    S s6[] = {0}; /* why is this allowed? */
    S s7 = {0, 0};
    S s8 = {0};
    S s9 = 0; /* error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'S' */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883867/1491895) for why `s5` and `s6` are allowed.

Comment: Read the part after "But you can also omit braces if you insist"